How to build and Install compiler g++-4.8.5 on ubuntu 24.04 from source code?
I am getting error while building gcc-4.8.5 on ubuntu 24.04
I had followed the below steps as mentioned in the page How to Install compiler g++-4.8.5 in ubuntu 20.04
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib libstdc++6:i386
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.bz2 --no-check-certificate
tar xf gcc-4.8.5.tar.bz2
sed -i -e 's/__attribute__/\/\/__attribute__/g' gcc-4.8.5/gcc/cp/cfns.h
sed -i 's/struct ucontext/ucontext_t/g' gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/config/i386/linux-unwind.h
mkdir xgcc-4.8.5
pushd xgcc-4.8.5
$PWD/../gcc-4.8.5/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-plugin --    program-suffix=-4.8.5
make MAKEINFO="makeinfo --force"
sudo make install

But, I got the make error as below:

gcc/reload1.c:89:24: error: use of an operand of type ‘bool’ in ‘operator++’ is forbidden in C++17    89 |   (this_target_reload->x_spill_indirect_levels)       |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../../gcc/reload1.c:443:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘spill_indirect_levels’   443 |       spill_indirect_levels++;


My guess is that the code that gives the error is built using the platform-standard compiler, which is new enough to default to C++17 mode. Or you have some environment variables which sets weird flags and options. You probably need to explicitly set CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS to default to the C++11 (or earlier, considering the age of the version 4.8) standard.

Out of curiosity - why do you want to build a 9 year old compiler?

Steps to build gcc-4.8.5 from source code on Ubuntu 24.04 machine:

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install build-essential libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev texinfo wget

sudo apt install make wget git gcc g++ lhasa libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev flex bison gettext texinfo ncurses-dev autoconf rsync

wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.8.5/gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz

tar -xzvf gcc-4.8.5.tar.gz

cd gcc-4.8.5

vi gcc/reload1.c                                         //open the reload1.c file and
//search for "spill_indirect_levels++" and replace
"spill_indirect_levels++"
AS
"spill_indirect_levels = 1"

sed -i -e 's/__attribute__/\/\/__attribute__/g' gcc/cp/cfns.h

sed -i 's/struct ucontext/ucontext_t/g' libgcc/config/i386/linux-unwind.h

sed -i '/#include <pthread.h>/a #include <signal.h>' libsanitizer/asan/asan_linux.cc

vi libsanitizer/tsan/tsan_platform_linux.cc             //open the tsan_platform_linux.cc file
//and search for "statp" and replace the below line:
"__res_state statp = ( __res_state)state;"
AS
"struct __res_state statp = (struct __res_state)state;"

vi libitm/config/linux/rwlock.cc                        //open the rwlock.cc file
// and search for "typeof"
and replace
"typeof"
AS
"__typeof__"  in the whole file

mkdir build

cd build

../configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-4.8.5 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib --disable-bootstrap

sudo make -j 24

sudo make install


